# Gardner riddle on mathemagicians

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, puzzle

A cute riddle (but maybe not so easy!) from Gardner:

At a gathering of mathemagicians, the Grand Master and his 8 disciples are seated at a round table. The Grand Master will judge each of his displices on their newest trick. After he has seen all the performances, the Grand Master hands to each of his disciples a card with their score on it (the score is some integer number of points greater than $0$). In return, The Grand Master then performs the trick himself and allows his disciples to judge his own perforamce. The disciples agree on a score and give the Grand Master a card with his score on it. It turns out that each mathemagician at the table has a different score.

The Grand Master then remarks: "I can think of a number that divides the product of my own score and the score of anyone seated at this table, other than the two people sitting beside me.". Each of the disciples look at their own scorecard and then look around the table, and each discplie remarks: "I can also think of such a number!". All at once, everyone seated at the table announces the number they have in mind. Incredibly, they all say same the same number! "Now that is some trick!" the Grand Master laughs.

What is the smallest possible number the mathemagicians could have announced?

Comment: So the Grand Master knows everyone else's score, but everyone else only knows their own score and the Grand Masters'?

Comment: @Meelo I think everyone knows all of the scores ... ?

Comment: Everyone can see eacother's scores.

Comment: Well, if you assign everyone's score to be a product of 8 of the first 10 primes, where they share 7 terms of the product with their neighbor and less with anyone else (and this is indeed possible - just put those primes in a 10-cycle and cycle each person's factorization), then the product of the first 10 primes satisfies the desired property. This is a rather big number though and I can't prove it's the *smallest*.

Comment: 7 of the first 9 primes, but otherwise great answer

Comment: Sambalsambal , please consider posting the answer or at the least, a link to the original question/ name of the book this was taken from .

Answer (score 2):

The Grand Master top-scores with a mere $3^2 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 11 = 121275$ and the other scores are:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\hline \text{Disciple} & \text{Score} & \text{Composition} \\
\hline 1 & 80850 & 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 7 \times 7 \times 11 \times 2  \\
\hline 2 & 53900 & 5 \times 5 \times 7 \times 7 \times 11 \times 2 \times 2  \\
\hline 3 & 32340 & 5 \times 7 \times 7 \times 11 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3  \\
\hline 4 & 19404 & 7 \times 7 \times 11 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3  \\
\hline 5 & 13860 & 7 \times 11 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5  \\
\hline 6 & 9900 & 11 \times 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5  \\
\hline 7 & 6300 & 2 \times 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 7  \\
\hline 8 & 22050 & 2 \times 3 \times 3 \times 5 \times 5 \times 7 \times 7  \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

and the new marvellous number is $485100$

(thanks to Prajanan Pate for the improvement)

---

*original answer*

So the Grand Master scores highly, of course, getting $5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 = 37182145$

The remaining disciples, in order round the table, get:
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|} 
\hline \text{Disciple} & \text{Score} & \text{Composition} \\
\hline 1 & 14872858 & 2 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \\
\hline 2 & 6374082 & 2 \times 3 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \\
\hline 3 & 2897310 & 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \\
\hline 4 & 1560090 & 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 17 \times 19 \times 23 \\
\hline 5 & 1009470 & 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 19 \times 23 \\
\hline 6 & 690690 & 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 23 \\
\hline 7 & 510510 & 2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \\
\hline 8 & 4849845 & 3 \times 5 \times 7 \times 11 \times 13 \times 17 \times 19 \\
\hline \end{array}
$$

and the "incredible" number is $23\#=223092870$.

... and the field is open for a lower number!

Comment: Can you please explain how you arrived at the answer and why this is the smallest ?  Also, you say, "comment from Prajanan Patel", etc but there are no comments here . So, if this question was discussed somewhere also then request you to please post a link to that discussion .

Comment: @HemantAgarwal I guess the comment was deleted - and probably by the person who posted it once I updated to incorporate their improvement. The idea here is that there is a marvellous number with a lot of factors, and everyone has a number that is missing two prime factors. The people adjacent are also missing one of the same factors; going round the table other people can naturally supply those missing factors.

Comment: Firstly, how did you realise that everyone has a number that is missing two prime factors ? Why can't everybody miss just one factor ?  Secondly , how does one figure out what the optimum marvellous number would be? is it just trial and error? Even you seemed to have found a sub optimal marvellous number in your first attempt : 223092870 ...

Comment: I had a good scheme initially, but I missed the potential for using repeated factors in the marvellous number - my first thought (six years ago now) that all the factors would need to be different. But squares are usable.

Comment: Firstly, how did you realise that everyone has a number that is missing two prime factors ? Why can't everybody miss just one factor ?

Comment: You have to miss two prime factors to be different from each of your two neighbors. Remember that that your two neighbors are not neighbors to each other so they need to have different numbers.

Comment: There are a total of 9 prime  factors of your marvellous number  $$2^2 \times 3^2 \times 5^2 \times 7^2 \times 11 = 485100$$  Can a marvellous number consisting of less than  9  prime factors  satisfy the condition that the product of each person with everybody else, other than his immediate neighbours,  is divisible by the marvellous number? This marvellous number can be even more than 485100 but it should have less than 9 prime factors . I ask because I am trying to prove that the marvellous number will have at least/exactly  9 prime factors, but cannot figure how to prove this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122549/discussion-between-joffan-and-hemant-agarwal).

Answer (score -1):

What about 2, 2, 3, 3, 5, 5, 2, 7 11 = 138600

Comment: That doesn't work. If you just do the calculations you'll find several cases of the product of two wizards sitting next to each other whose scores multiply to a number divisble by 138600.