# Integers Positioned Around a Circle

Tags: number-theory

Nine distinct positive integers are arranged in a circle such that the product of any two non-adjacent numbers in the circle is a multiple of n and the product of any two adjacent numbers in the circle is not a multiple of n, where n is a fixed positive integer. What is the smallest possible value for n.

Comment: This seems quite similar to [this recent Question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1106065/gardner-riddle-on-mathemagicians).  The statement of requirements here is actually a good bit easier for me to follow than the "riddle" formulation there.

Comment: I'm not sure that's the smallest.  I had difficulty interpreting the earlier problem in a nontrivial way, so I did not try to solve it myself.  If you can show an assignment of nine numbers that improves to $n=138600$, then certainly it would be worth posting that as an Answer to the other Question.

Comment: I simply mean giving the circular list of nine distinct positive integers, as called for by your problem.

Comment: It is not consistent with site policy to drastically alter your question to copy the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n = \prod_{j=1}^m p_j^{e_j}$ is the prime factorization of $n$.
Let $x_0, \ldots, x_8$ be your nine numbers (we do arithmetic modulo 9 on indices of $x$).  For each $i = 0 \ldots 8$ there is some $j$ such that $x_i x_{i+1}$ is not divisible by $p_j^{e_j}$.   We can't use the same prime for $x_i x_{i+1}$ and
$x_{j} x_{j+1}$ if $i,i+1,j,j+1$ are all distinct, because $x_i x_{i+1} x_j x_{j+1} = (x_i x_j)(x_{i+1} x_{j+ 1})$, and $x_i x_j$ and $x_{i+1} x_{j+1}$ are divisible by $p_j^{e_j}$.  So we need at least five different primes. 
Moreover, if we use the same prime for $x_i x_{i+1}$ and $x_{i+1} x_{i+2}$,
$e_j \ge 2$ ($e_j = 1$ wouldn't work, since $x_i x_{i+2}$ must be divisible by $p_j^{e_j}$).

To minimize $n$, we take the five least primes $2,3,5,7,11$, and we may take $e_j = 2$ for the first four and $1$ for $11$, obtaining $n = 485100$